# IIS Application Pool User can't access UNC drive

Tags: rest, authentication, iis, credentials, unc

I have a VM running Windows 2012 R2, on which are running a web site, Rest API, and a couple of services.

The services and Rest APIs need access to a specific UNC path, which requires a username and password to authenticate.

So, I set up a User, logged in as that User, and added the details to the Credentials Manager:-

cmdkey /add:server\path /user:domain\username /pass:encryptedpassword

When logged in as that User, I can now open File Explorer and go to server\path and have full access to all the files.

I updated the services to log in as that User, and they have full access to that UNC path, and can do their thing quite happily.

But I can't get the Rest API to have access to that path.

I've opened IIS Manager, gone to Application Pools, and selected my RestAPI pool. I then clicked Advanced Options, went to Identity, and changed the details to my User with access to the UNC drives.

I've added the User to the IIS_IUSRS group, and they were already set for 'Logon as Service' for the services.

I've saved it all, and restarted the RestAPI.

The RestAPI otherwise all works. I can log in to the web site, move around and get the correct data etc, all of which comes from the RestAPI.

However, the moment I try to access something on the UNC drive, it fails with

```
System.IO.IOException: The user name or password is incorrect.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
```

Given that everything else works, clearly that user does have the correct username and password saved in their credentials, which implies that for some reason IIS isn't picking those credentials up.

I tried setting the IIS App Pool identity to:-

Domain\User

.\User

User

None of them will work with the UNC path.

I've tried Googling around, but not got anywhere.

Help me, Stack-Ovi Kerflowbi, you're my only hope!

Edit : One thing I forgot to mention...

The RestAPI works perfectly on other sites where it doesn't need saved credentials to get to files, it's running on about 20 sites with no problem at all.

It's just this one where it needs credentials to access the UNC path that we get the error.

Comment: Could you please post the details codes about your rest api? According to your error message, it seems the username and password is not right. Besies, I suggest you could check the application pool identity to make sure the username and password is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the solution was pretty simple, just buried under a relatively obscure setting.

In the main post, I said...

> I've opened IIS Manager, gone to Application Pools, and selected my
>   RestAPI pool. I then clicked Advanced Options, went to Identity, and
>   changed the details to my User with access to the UNC drives.

Turns out I missed a step while I was there.

Still on the Advanced Settings page, there's an option '**Load User Profile**'.

In order for IIS to use the credentials set up for the User, that setting needs to be set to **True**.

Once I did that, I restarted the RestAPI and it had full access to the UNC drive.